# ERROR: MethodError: no method matching ccolor(::Type{ColorTypes.Gray{FixedPointNumbers.Normed{UInt8,8}}}, ::Type{Nothing}) in Julia

Tags: julia

I get the following error when loading maps in Julia:

```
ERROR: MethodError: no method matching ccolor(::Type{ColorTypes.Gray{FixedPointNumbers.Normed{UInt8,8}}}, ::Type{Nothing})
Closest candidates are:
  ccolor(::Type{Cdest<:ColorTypes.Colorant}, ::Type{Csrc<:ColorTypes.Colorant}) where {Cdest<:Colorant, Csrc<:Colorant} at /Users/logankilpatrick/.julia/packages/ColorTypes/BsAWO/src/traits.jl:259
  ccolor(::Type{Cdest<:(ColorTypes.Color{T,1} where T)}, ::Type{T<:Number}) where {Cdest<:(Color{T,1} where T), T<:Number} at /Users/logankilpatrick/.julia/packages/ColorTypes/BsAWO/src/traits.jl:260
Stacktrace:
 [1] convert(::Type{ColorTypes.Gray{FixedPointNumbers.Normed{UInt8,8}}}, ::Nothing) at /Users/logankilpatrick/.julia/packages/ColorTypes/BsAWO/src/conversions.jl:7
 [2] ColorTypes.Gray{FixedPointNumbers.Normed{UInt8,8}}(::Nothing) at /Users/logankilpatrick/.julia/packages/ColorTypes/BsAWO/src/types.jl:446
 [3] _broadcast_getindex_evalf at ./broadcast.jl:574 [inlined]
 [4] _broadcast_getindex at ./broadcast.jl:547 [inlined]
 [5] getindex at ./broadcast.jl:507 [inlined]
 [6] copy at ./broadcast.jl:734 [inlined]
 [7] materialize(::Base.Broadcast.Broadcasted{Base.Broadcast.DefaultArrayStyle{0},Nothing,Type{ColorTypes.Gray{FixedPointNumbers.Normed{UInt8,8}}},Tuple{Base.RefValue{Nothing}}}) at ./broadcast.jl:724
```

The error references a function I use called loadgraymap defined as follows: `loadgraymap(filename::String)  = Gray{N0f8}.(FileIO.load(filename)) |> transpose`

It interestingly works the first time it is called but doesn't work the 2nd time it's called.  Any advice on how to fix this issue? I do not have any problem with v0.6 of Julia.  I also get the following warning: `WARNING: QuartzImageIO: indexed color images not implemented` but I am unsure what it means

Here is where I call the method:

```
holderVar.zone_map  = loadcolormap(map_file_name(sim_params, "Zone"))   
holderVar.depth_map = loadgraymap(map_file_name(sim_params, "Depth"))

#temp_slope_map  = loadgraymap(map_file_name(sim_params, "Slope"))
#holderVar.slope_map = (someFakeNum/someFakeNum) .* (someFakeNum .- temp_slope_map)                       
#temp_elev_map   = loadgraymap(map_file_name(sim_params, "Elevation"))
#holderVar.elev_map  = someFakeNum * someFakeNum .* temp_elev_map
```

Note that the first 2 calls of it work fine! I just commented it out so I could keep working through different errors I was having. I also change the variable names above to make it look more general!

Comment: can you post where you call the method?

Comment: @melanzane yes I just updated it above